# Redundant to inherit from Object in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

As stated above, is it redundant to inherit from Object in c#?
Do both sets of code below result in equivalent objects being defined?

```
class TestClassUno : Object
{
    // Stuff
}
```

vs.

```
class TestClassDos
{
    // Stuff
}
```

I snooped around on MSDN but wasn't able to find anything perfectly conclusive.

Comment: Any class definition that doesn't explicitly specify a base class will inherit from `object` implicitly.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If left unspecified every `class` definition will implicitly inherit from `System.Object` hence the two definitions are equivalent.

The only time these two would be different is if someone actually defined another `Object` type in the same namespace.  In this case the local definition of `Object` would take precedence and change the inheritance object

```
namespace Example {
  class Object { } 
  class C : Object { } 
}
```

Very much a corner case but wouldn't point it out if I hadn't seen it before

Note that the same is not true if you used `object` instead of `Object`.  The C# keyword `object` is a type alias for `System.Object` and hence it wouldn't match `Example.Object`.

```
namespace Example2 { 
  class Object { } 
  class C : Object { } // Uses Example.Object
  class D : object { } // Uses System.Object
}
```

Of course if you have a truly evil developer you could still cause confusion with `object`

```
namespace System { 
  class Object { 
    private Object() { } 
  }
}

namespace Example3 {
  // This will properly fail to compile since it can't bind to the private
  // Object constructor.  This demonstrates that we are using our definition
  // of Object instead of mscorlib's 
  class C : object { } // Uses our System.Object
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the local `Example.Object` still inherit from `System.Object` ?

Comment: @Aren the local `Object` indeed would but `C` in this case would inherit from `Example.Object`

Comment: @Aren: Yes, but Jared's point is that in this case, writing `C : Object` is not redundant.

Comment: @Aren I would think that, ultimately, it would... but the middle/local "Object" could be overwritten, modified, extended... Unless I understand this wrong.

Comment: @JaredPar & @WernerCD, I only really asked because it seemed a bit out of scope for the question. Understandably yes, someone could write a local `Object` class and override functionality, but that didn't seem part of the scope to me. My question was partially rhetorical since I was implying that ultimately the resulting class would still be in the inheritance tree of `System.Object`.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, everything ultimately inherits from an object if defined as `class`. Leave the explicit inheritance out of your code.

Comment: @Cicada: `struct` derives *directly* from System.ValueType. It does also derive from System.Object (everything does eventually), but struct types don't even apply to the OP because they can only implement interfaces; a construct declared as a struct can never derive directly from anything but ValueType.

Comment: [Not everything derives from object](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx) (Pointer types do not. Also Interfaces, and open parameter types (`typeof(List<>)`) are things you can represent as a `Type` but do not derive from Object)

Answer (score 8):

Yes it is redundant to inherit from object in class

Answer (score 8):

MSDN : [Object class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) : Supports all classes in the .NET Framework class hierarchy and provides low-level services to derived classes. This is the ultimate base class of all classes in the .NET Framework; it is the root of the type hierarchy.

Check this research : [inherits from object? An investigation into how.](http://www.ytechie.com/2009/04/int-inherits-from-object-an-investigation-into-how.html)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Object is the mother of all classes in .Net. There is nothing above it.

All classes inherit from it. So this code

```
class TestClassDos
{
    // Stuff
}
```

automatically means it is inheriting from object.

**Proof**: You can typecast any entity to object which is possible if it is inheriting from it.

Summary of Object class says

```
// Supports all classes in the .NET Framework class hierarchy and provides low-level
// services to derived classes. This is the ultimate base class of all classes
// in the .NET Framework; it is the root of the type hierarchy.
```

Comment: You will also find `.ToString()` in interfaces in .NET, yet interfaces don't inherit from `System.Object`. (I agree with your conclusion, just not with the proof you give.)

Comment: @hvd: But ultimately interfaces will be implemented by classes.

Comment: Yes, or by structs, which also inherit from `object`. But my point is that the fact that `.ToString()` is available is only because of a special exception in the compiler that adds `object`'s members even for some types that don't actually inherit from `object`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are both the same thing, I don't think I saw anyone mention structs, but all objects (that is regardless if you declare a class or a struct) they all ultimately inherit from **Object**, see this [Object MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173110%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) and this other article on [Structs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/saxz13w4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There *is* a time when inheriting from `object` makes sense — when you have a `partial class` definition, and you want to lock down inheritance and prevent other partial declarations from extending a different class. Attempting to inherit from another type in the partial class will then give you the [CS0263 Compiler Error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0263).

This only makes sense in the event that your partial class is not already inheriting from another type.

The `partial` keyword is not in your code example, but I thought it might be worth mentioning as I found my way here from Google after seeing a similar setup in an API. Aside from inheriting from `object`s that don't point to the official `System.Object` as others pointed out, there is no benefit in doing so as all classes inherit from `object` implicitly.